# Using the eraser tool but after applying changes a brush stroke still appears

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

I'm trying to erase part of an image, but every time I apply the eraser tool a stroke appears like the circle of the eraser tool.

Comment: Hi Madison, welcome to GD.SE! Can you post a gif/video of your problem? As it stands your post is likely to be closed without further information for us to help you out!

Comment: Illustrator's Eraser Tool doesn't work *anything* like Photoshops Eraser. In fact, I think they should *remove that tool* form Illustrator altogether. it's merely misleading, and unnecessary.

Comment: @Scott for Illustrator lead product designer!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're referring to, is erasing parts of a *path*... which creates anchor points to subtract from the shape, if that's the case;

**That is how the eraser tool works.**

---

Note, it doesn't actually create a stroke, but rather it *removes* an area from the shape in the way of a stroke since you are "erasing" [**[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXWzg.gif)**]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to "erase" part of a shape is to use the Pathfinder tool. Make a shape, like a square, or any other shape, and place it above the shape you want to erase. Then select both shapes, and choose the Minus Front button in Pathfinder, and it will erase the bottom shape using the overlap of the top shape. It will make more sense once you try it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this all you need to do is delete the clipping group which is visible on you Layers Panel.

That's the problem, once Clipping group for that specific layer is deleted, hey presto no nasty lines.

Comment: How on earth do you know there's a clipping group????